# I want to open User Id base profile page in angular 4

Tags: angular, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to open user profile page in angular 4 for that :-

I have send Profile API from backend :-

```
http://localhost:3001/my_profile/2.json/?api_token=Uq3cv0E4UukGRolYO3x4p-Zog7rnVqefj1uMGaq7EGA
```

Then I am confused how to call Userid(2) dynamically in service

```
doProfile(token: any){
    let data = new URLSearchParams();
    data.append('api_token', token);
    return this.http.get(this.url+'my_profile/userId.json?'+'api_token='+token).map((response: Response) => response.json());
}
```

Comment: Use it like `this.http.get(\`${this.url}my_profile/${userId}.json?api_token=${token}\`)...`

Answer (score 0):

Pass parameter to `doProfile` function and use it to form URL, and then since you already created `URLSearchParams` pass it to `params` property of `http` options.

```
doProfile(token: any, userId: number){
    let data = new URLSearchParams();
    data.append('api_token', token);
    return this.http.get(`${this.url}my_profile/${userId}.json`, {params: data })
           .map((response: Response) => response.json());
}
```

Comment: That is what i want to know. how to send userId.                                                                this.friendservice.doProfile(this.globalService.user_token).subscribe((response: any) => {
      
      this.peopleKnow = response;
      this.loading = false;
    });

Comment: @RahulWadhwa so with the call to `doProfile` function you should pass `userId` as well `this.friendservice.doProfile(this.globalService.user_token, userId)`

Comment: Working Now, Thanks